# Showing all the possible values of a field in App Maker dropdown

Tags: google-app-maker

I need to create a filter which gets all the possible values for a concrete field, but I'm only getting the values which appears in the current page.

[image]

**Result**

[image]

What can I do to get all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to filter table basing on value in the dropdown. In order to do this you need to bind your dropdown's value to datasource's filter:

`@datasources.MyData.query.filters.Country._equals`

then you need to reload your datasource every time when user changes dropdown's value

```javascript
// onValueEdit
app.datasources.MyData.load();
```

You can play with this sample app to learn more: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/project-list/

Comment: That is what i'm doing... but the dropdown only shows the values that are loaded in the current page... for example, if i'm in the page 1 of the list, the dropdown will show the list of countries that appears on the page 1. If i go to the page 2, it will show the list of countries of the page 2...

Comment: Ah! Got it. It looks like you are using same datasource for your dropdown and table and you are doing subquery of a subquery. You need to have separate datasource for your dropdown. Creating Calculated Model that would squeeze unique country values from your table should work. You can also consider moving countries to separate model to normalize your DB.